# Changing the value of textbox when Selecting a value from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i'm currently developing an Employee Management System, and I Want to change the value of salary when changing the value of Drop Down List, So Here is my Table
[table_sg_step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaHRU.png), this is my code for
**Index.php**

1. **Drop Down List for Salary**

   **Salary Grade**

   ```
                                                <?php 

                                                   $query = "SELECT salary_grade FROM salarygrade_step";
                                                   $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                                                ?>
                                                <?php 
                                                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                                                   {
                                                       $sg = $row['salary_grade'];
                                                       echo "<option value = '$sg'>
                                                                $sg
                                                            </option>";
                                                   }         
                                                ?>
                                                </select>
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Please provide a valid Salary Grade
                                                    </div> 
                                            </div>
   ```

**2. Drop Down List for Step**

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                                <label><strong> Step </strong></label>
                                                    <select class="custom-select" id="step" name = "step">
                                                        <option value = "Step_1">Step 1</option>
                                                        <option value = "Step_2">Step 2</option>    
                                                        <option value = "Step_3">Step 3</option>    
                                                        <option value = "Step_4">Step 4</option>    
                                                        <option value = "Step_5">Step 5</option>
                                                        <option value = "Step_6">Step 6</option>
                                                        <option value = "Step_7">Step 7</option> 
                                                        <option value = "Step_8">Step 8</option>  
                                                    </select>
                                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Please provide a valid Salary Grade
                                                    </div> 
                                            </div>
```

And for my Ajax
3. AJAX

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                                            $("step").on('change',function(){
                                                var step = $(this).val();

                                                if(step)
                                                {
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        type    :   'GET',
                                                        url     :   'regular_get_salary.php',
                                                        data    :   {reg_step:step},
                                                        success :   function(response){document.getElementById("salary").val = response;}
                                                    });  
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
```

This is my code for **regular_get_salary.php**

```
    <?php

session_start();

include_once('security.php');

$salarygrade       =   mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['salarygrade']);
$step       =   mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['step']);
$salary       =   mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['salary']);

if(isset($_POST['reg_step'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM salarygrade_step WHERE salary_grade = $salarygrade";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
        if($step == "Step_1"){
            echo $row['Step_1'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_2"){
            echo $row['Step_2'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_3"){
            echo $row['Step_3'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_4"){
            echo $row['Step_4'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_5"){
            echo $row['Step_5'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_6"){
            echo $row['Step_6'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_7"){
            echo $row['Step_7'];
        }
        elseif($step == "Step_8"){
            echo $row['Step_8'];
        }
       
    }
}
?>
```

So Basically once I Change the value of salary Grade and Step, it will automatically change the value of textbox(Salary) base on the given value (see the table_sg_step) .. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please `print_r($_POST)` and check what it gives you before setting `$salarygrade` in `regular_get_salary.php` because it seems like you are trying to use `type    :   'GET',` method in ajax and calling `$_POST` also since you are passing only `data    :   {reg_step:step},` so your `$salarygrade` won't be getting variable from the ajax call. You might want to try something like this

```
data    :   {"reg_step":step,
             "salarygrade": someVariable,
             "step": someVariable
             "salary": someVariable
},
```

and in your php use `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the recommendation of  sir adi

I modified my ajax to
`$.ajax({ type    :   "GET", url     :   "regular_get_salary.php", data    :   {   _step : step, _salarygrade: salarygrade}, success :   function(response) { document.getElementById("salary").val = response; $('#salary').html(response); } });`

and in the PHP i changed it to `if(isset($_GET['_step']) && isset($_GET['_salarygrade'])){`